# Pass a string parameter to Jenkins declarative script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am declaring a String Parameter in Jenkins -

```
Name is SLACKTOKEN 
Value is qwsaw2345
```

My Jenkins file has script

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'trial' }

    stages {
        stage("Build Docker Image") {
            steps{
                sh 'docker build -t trial:latest --build-arg SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET=${SLACKTOKEN}'
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I tried like this, but it didnt work. Could you please let me know how can I pass a value from Jenkins string parameter to Jenkins declarative script file.
I have added the Password parameter in job like below

[image]

Comment: There is no `parameters` block in your code, so where is it being declared?

Comment: @MattSchuchard, If I add parameters block in my code, then I need to pass the value also, right. Is there any option that I can take it  from Jenkins Password parameter

Comment: Are you talking about using the Jenkins Credentials plugin? That would be different than a parameter.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Please refer the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `parameters` directive you can provide parameters, details is [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters).

To pass parameter use `params.SLACKTOKEN` inside double quotes, not single:

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'trial' }
    parameters {
        password(name: 'SLACKTOKEN', defaultValue: '', description: 'Slack Token')
    }
    stages {
        stage("Build Docker Image") {
            steps{
                sh "docker build -t trial:latest --build-arg SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET=${params.SLACKTOKEN}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But then again i need to pass the secret value here. But I wanted to declare as in config. Please check the screenshot

Comment: Use `password(name: 'PASSWORD', defaultValue: 'SECRET', description: 'Enter a password')`

Comment: Then where I will pass the value "qwsaw2345" for SLACKTOKEN ?

Comment: Put your "qwsaw2345" to `defaultValue`. If your parameter will not change use `credentials` to store you token, it's secure.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you declared your variable?

There are a lot of options:

Example: Use env section from declarative syntax:

```
    pipeline {
        agent {
            label 'trial'
        }

        environment {
            SLACKTOKEN = 'qwsaw2345'
        }

        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    sh "docker build -t trial:latest --build-arg SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET=${SLACKTOKEN}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to declare the variable like that. I wanted to select the option This project is parameterised from Jenkins config and in that pass it as  password parameter.

Comment: So add correct code with parameters section as without that we cannot help you

Comment: added screenshot